# Storing the Date and Time in a SQL Database on Android

Tags: android, sql, datetime

I'm attempting to store 3 values in a database I've created on an android device. The values are NAME, DATE, and TIME. My question is thus: what is the best approach to fetch and store the current DATE and TIME values when they are inserted into the database?

So far I have identified two ways to do this, either by making system calls in android like  `//values.put(TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());`  or using SQL functions like `GETDATE()`. But, which is better?

If I'm heading off in the wrong direction, please let me know and direct me towards the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the SQL functions will be more compatible with other tools using the same SQL engine.

Using text in ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fff` will be widely compatible and still sort properly.

Answer (score 2):

The [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) give these column type options for storing dates:

- TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714   B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

You could use TEXT as described by Doug Currie, or you could use INTEGER using a [java.util.Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html). (I don't know why you'd use the REAL option.)

To use INTEGER, you could load and store dates something like this:

```
// build a date from a Cursor
Date d = new Date(cursor.getLong(DATE_FIELD_INDEX));

// add a date to an SQLiteDatabase
final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DATE_FIELD, d.getTime());
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

This will be less readable in your database, but comparisons between dates (in your query) should be faster since comparing numbers is faster than strings. (Although I don't know much about the sqlite implementation.)